# Undoing a git commit on a folder that contains many other folders

Tags: git

I have a main folder called `code` which has many other folders, each one an individual project. I created a new folder called `project2` but forgot to `cd project2` before I hit `git init`... and am now accidentally tracking the entire `code` folder.
Now, my the entire `code` folder is being tracked and shows `(master) code`! :/

How can I remove this entire commit without it impacting the rest of my files inside the `code` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the git data is stored in a `.git` folder in your `code` directory. If you remove this folder, the newly created git repository is gone and you can create a new git repository in the subfolder `project2`.

Comment: Thanks! Presumably the command would be `git rm -rf .git`? I only want to remove this one and not all the other gits from my other folders

Comment: It's not a git command, just `rm -rf .git` – and it won't affect separate git repositories in the subfolders.

Comment: `rm -rf .git` accomplished exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!